# Why getLastLocation returns null?

Tags: android, maps

I am trying to solve this over 3 days. I have lost my sight of debugging and not able to see my mistake.
I am trying to build an application that requests the current location.

My getLastLocation returns null, can any one point me where I am doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
public class MapActivityFragment extends FragmentActivity implements 
        LocationListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener, View.OnClickListener {

    //Our Map
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    //To store longitude and latitude from map
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;

    //Google ApiClient
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private ImageButton buttonCurrent;
    private TextView tv;
    private String myLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTv);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //Initializing googleapi client
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        buttonCurrent = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonCurrent);
        buttonCurrent.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Initializing views and adding onclick listeners
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        // Log.d("Tag Name", "GOOGLE  : : :  " + googleApiClient);
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onResume();
    }

    //Getting current location
    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        //mMap.clear();
        //Creating a location object
        Log.d("Tag Name", "GOOGLE  : : :  " + googleApiClient);
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        Log.d("Tag Name", "asdsa " + location);
        Toast.makeText(MapActivityFragment.this, "googleApiclient:" + googleApiClient, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(MapActivityFragment.this, "location:" + location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mMap.clear();

        if (location != null) {
            Log.d("Tag Name", "2222");
            //Getting longitude and latitude
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            tv.setText("longitude: " + longitude + " " + "latitude: " + latitude);

            //Toast.makeText(this, "long ; " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("Tag Name", "Log Message");

            //moving the map to location
            moveMap();
        }
    }

    //Function to move the map
    private void moveMap() {

        //String to display current latitude and longitude
        String msg = latitude + " , " + longitude;
        //Creating a LatLng Object to store Coordinates
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        //Adding marker to map
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng) //setting position
                .draggable(true) //Making the marker draggable
                .title("Current Location")); //Adding a title
        //Moving the camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        //Animating the camera
        //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        //Displaying current coordinates in toast
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Location services connected.");
        getCurrentLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        mMap.clear();
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .draggable(true));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
        longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;
        moveMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == buttonCurrent) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            getCurrentLocation();
            //moveMap();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(40, 40)).title("Hello World"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();
        tv.setText("Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude = " + location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
}
```

Comment: how about permissions? Have added required permissions at manifest (and request at runtime since API23)?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: and runtime permission check? Are You developing on API =>23?

Comment: Yes above of permissions mentioned by Karo remember to turn your GPS or what ever location service on?

Comment: runtime permission check? YES
GPS is on

Comment: @Opiatefuchs how to check runtime permission?

Comment: see here: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Please , write program that show my current location.I need it.

Comment: where does getLastLocation() gets location coordinates from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me, some changes from Google provided.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
    // Display the connection status
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        requestLocationPermission();
        return;
    }
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location != null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "GPS location was found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        startLocationUpdates();
}
```

Permission model code is for API level >= 23

Mention some logs from your RUN in next edit for more help.

EDIT
requestLocationPermission() to ask user to permit to use that permission enable.

```
        protected void requestLocationPermission() {
        Log.i(TAG, "LOCATION permission has NOT been granted. Requesting permission.");

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
            // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
            // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.
            Log.i(TAG,
                    "Displaying location permission rationale to provide additional context.");
// some snackbar thingy
        } else {
            // Camera permission has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS_LOCATION,
                    REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
    }
```

Comment: requestLocationPermission(); ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
android.location.Location bestLocation = null;
for (String provider : providers) {
    android.location.Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (l == null) {
        continue;
    }
    if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
        // Found best last known location: %s", l);
        bestLocation = l;
    }
}
//bestlocation is required location
```

Answer (score 0):

`getLastKnownLocation` will return null if there is no cached last known location. Unlike what people think the OS does not guarantee to store the last location it received in memory, in my experience this changes from device to device, so you should always check for null and deal accordingly.

So, to actually answer your question, if the last known location is null you need to get or wait for the current location.

http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: where does getLastLocation() gets location coordinates from?